# Weird behavior while invoking Rest call using Invoke-RestMethod on Powershell script

Tags: powershell, rest, get, invoke-restmethod

I want to pass body(parameters) to Rest-call using **Invoke-RestMethod**(powershell script) in **GET** call. but I think it's not supported because of some security reasons(some RFC standards).

But in single session, When I first use **POST** method and then if I use **GET** method then it works. but if I directly call get method then it's throwing below **error**.

```
Invoke-RestMethod : The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send
```

So, Is there some information powershell stores after first call ? Also, Is there any way to pass parameters to "GET" Restcall in powershell script ?

I've attached code snippet:
this snippet is working.

```
Invoke-RestMethod 'https://test_url/url_path?param1=par' -Method 'POST' -Headers $headers

Invoke-RestMethod 'https://test_url/url_path?param1=par' -Method 'GET' -Headers $headers  # works
```

but this throws the error,

```
Invoke-RestMethod 'https://test_url/url_path?param1=par' -Method 'GET' -Headers $headers #Not works
```

Comment: perhaps this might help https://blog.darrenjrobinson.com/powershell-the-underlying-connection-was-closed-an-unexpected-error-occurred-on-a-send/

Comment: @codebrane I tried same thing mentioned in blog, still getting same error. 
Do you know any other lib/way by which we can call get method with parameters in powershell script?